# how to generate barcode in laravel with size limit

Tags: php, laravel

I want to generate a barcode in my project. I have installed the milon/barcode package but the barcode which is generated by this library seems long in term of length. I Would like to generate a barcode with a smaller length, even though the barcode string or number is too large.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah!  You can Set a limit which you want .
 
In first Step pick the specific attribute name from DB table 
2- implement For each loop  in  that file where where you want to print barcod
3- set limit size parameter which is give below like 1,13 respectively 
6- make class code in style tag and set height inside 
7- go to vendor -> milion->barcode->src->Milion->DNS1d -> line no 142
8- Add class="code " in html tag its works properly

```
@section('content')
@foreach($producto as $product)
<dir>
    {!!  DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($product->name, "C128" ,1,13)!!}


</dir>
<div style="padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 45px;  width: 500px;">
        {{$product->name}}   Rs{{$product->price}} <br>
        www.assorttech.com


</div>
@endforeach

<style> 
    .code{
        height: 60px !important;
    }

</style>
    @endsection
```

Step two  in DNS1D file  only add class code in following code

```
$html .= '<div class="code" style="background-color:' . $color . ';width:' . $bw . 'px;height:' . $bh . 'px;position:absolute;left:' . $x . 'px;top:' . $y . 'px;">&nbsp;</div>' . "\n";
        }
```